# 404 before or after 301 from http to https

Tags: http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

We expose our entire website solely over https. To do so we redirect all http requests to the corresponding https page with a 301 status code.

Say that a visitor browses to `http://ourdomain.com/nonexistingpage`

What statuscode should they receive first? 404 because the page doesn't exist, or a 301 to move to the https version of the nonexistingpage where a 404 will be issued? What difference, if any, would this make to Google, when ranking our website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would perform the 301 before the 404 to inform the client that the first address is not allowed - regardless of whether it exists.  301 also keeps any google rankings intact, but shifts them to the new location (from what I have read).  In this case it probably doesn't matter much for ranking because either one will ultimately result in a 404 (so they aren't included anyway).